# Objective C to Swift translator?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I literally need to translate one line of code from Objective C to Swift, any takers? This is a line from the tutorial in the link below.

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue;
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1

Also if there was a reference book/website that could do so, that would be amazing

Answer (score 4):

That's an Objective-C method interface declaration, which Swift doesn't have or need. You'd just use the implementation of the method:

```
@IBAction func unwindToList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // do something
}
```